# android: Softkeyboard perform action when Done key is pressed

Tags: android, key, listener, android-softkeyboard

I have an EditText. I want that after typing some text, when user presses the `Done` key of the softkeyboard, it should directly perform some search operation which I have also implemented in a button click event.

Comment: Better way with Kotlin in this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48810268/1912924

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Try this

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
            //do something
        }
    return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 20):

Try this

It works both for **DONE** and **RETURN**.

```
EditText editText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                        KeyEvent event) {
                    if (event != null && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER
                            || actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                        // Do your action
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You catch the `KeyEvent` and then check its keycode. `FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION` is used to identify enter keys that are coming from an IME whose enter key has been auto-labelled "next" or "done"

```
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.FLAG_EDITOR_ACTION)
    //your code here
```

Find the docs [**here**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html).

**Second Method**

```
myEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView view, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    int result = actionId & EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION;
    switch(result) {
    case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE:
        // done stuff
        break;
    case EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT:
        // next stuff
        break;
    }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

This will work in both condition whether your keyboard is showing enter sign or next arrow sign

```
YourEdittextName.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event)
        {
            if(actionId== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE||actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT)
            {
                //Perform Action here 
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

if u r facing red line then do this...
import Keyevent and EditorInfo by pressing alt+enter
then all the errors remove it will properly.......

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin use

```
viewBinding.editText.setOnEditorActionListener { view, actionId, event ->
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        //react to action
    }
    false
}
```

You can also return true inside 'if' braces to consume event - this way keyboard won't go down when you press done