# Call android activity after pin code screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am following this tutorial on creating basic pin code screens: http://lomza.totem-soft.com/pin-input-view-in-android/

I'm just stucked because I don't know how I would call another activity after the Pin code screen has been shown. I'm thinking that there's a button but I don't know where in the code exactly I would be putting the listener.

I just started studying android development so I'm not really familiar with it. Any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

@Senya is correct, the tutorial is pretty much basic stuff, there's no `Button` provided and you should add one yourself if you really want one.

However the whole point of a pin is quick access for the user so it is better if you don't provide a separate done button but just listen for the keys in `onKey()` method and verify the pin as correct, and you can launch your `Activity` if it is.

Answer (score 0):

In the tutorial just an example of PIN View without extra logic. You can add Button to layout or set [listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7584154/7721510) to EditText for EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE if you want.

Update: in this case listener should be added to the last EditText.

Comment: what do you mean in the last EditText?

Comment: In the tutorial for each digit uses an EditText. User expects **Done** action after entering last digit.